# Frosty's Question Unlocked?

Tags: discussion, locked

Considering the continuing interest and [media coverage](http://www.ksdk.com/story/news/nation/2013/10/22/3153549/) of the takedown of the Silk Road website and Dread Pirate Roberts, does it make sense to re-lock the linchpin [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445285/how-can-i-connect-to-a-tor-hidden-service-using-curl-in-php) that [brought it all down](http://www.slate.com/blogs/future_tense/2013/10/02/silk_road_s_dread_pirate_ross_ulbricht_asked_stack_overflow_question_under.html)?

I noticed the question was unlocked when I saw that [frosty got the Good Question badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/22/great-question?userid=1249338).

Also, I noticed a comment celebrating the unlocking of the question... bad omen?

Comment: Do you mean relock, rather than unlock?

Comment: I agree, it should be locked down again...for a very, very long time.

Comment: He received a good question badge, yes. It was a good question. Same thing applies for famous question (x2); it's a famous question.

Comment: Haha my comment celebrating it was not about frosty, but rather about that I gave it it's 100th upvote, which looks much better than 99. Yes, it should be locked, or it will generate too much discussion

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think locking it is a good idea, though not for the voting aspect, but for the media attention the question gets (and hence the noise generated by it being unlocked).

Just today, we've already already had comments about it being unlocked that we've deleted, and there's no sense in having a lightning rod around. Lock it, wait for everything to blow over, then worry about unlocking it -- if there's a need.

Comment: If there more noise is coming in, then lock it. That is what the lock is *for*. The OP was suggesting it be locked because it attracted *votes* though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There is noise coming in. That's why I locked it.

Comment: Can you change the staff note to "This question is locked to prevent off topic discussion..." as the answers are no longer locked? (or of course, lock the answers as well :))

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Actually, I also noticed the comment which raised red flags... just forgot to mention it.

Comment: As a side note his other question has also been locked and probably should be relocked

Comment: @JoeW: 'also has been *unlocked*' perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, it was unlocked also and unsure why I typed locked instead on unlocked.

Comment: _my favorite pattern is from MetaFilter, which is: When we start seeing effects of scale, we shut off the new user page. "Someone mentions us in the press and how great we are? Bye!" That's a way of raising the bar, that's creating a threshold of participation. And anyone who bookmarks that page and says "You know, I really want to be in there; maybe I'll go back later," that's the kind of user MeFi wants to have..._ (Clay Shirky, [A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy](http://www.shirky.com/writings/group_enemy.html))

Comment: PS. I removed the "historical question" notice since it's not really relevant to that particular post; so it's *just* perma-locked right now. We already have a Staff Note at the top explaining why it's locked anyways. :)

Comment: @animuson I couldn't see a way to easily lock all the answers and the question in one fell swoop without using the Historical Lock notice

Answer (score 6):

No, at least not because the question is being voted on.

Locking the question is only needed to prevent noise being posted (taunting comments, nonsense answers, etc.). We should care less if Frosty receives additional votes on that question or not. It's not as if internet points pay for his legal defense.

If the question attracts more noise again, then locking makes sense, but not before. The question itself still has value for future visitors, and you if you or anyone else has a better answer to the *core question*, then you should be able to post that.

*Update*: George Stocker re-locked the question, as it was indeed attracting more noise.

Comment: Wait, I *can't* play my lawyers in internet points? Oh boy are they going to be upset...

Comment: +1, though one could argue that the question *might* fall into this category: "*A question or answer where **repeated voting** or editing is happening in a way which attempts to game, hack, or otherwise abuse the system.*" I agree, though, that it does not yet appear to be a *serious* problem.

Comment: @JDB: Voting here is not *happening in a way which attempts to game, hack, or otherwise abuse the system*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Taking "abuse" to mean "misuse", I think the voting could easily have more to do with piling on to a famous question, exacerbated by the technically irrelevant comment inserted at the top (defacement?), than evaluating the question's technical merits. I still respect your general point, though.

Comment: @JDB Do you look at the top voted post much like, ever?  They're virtually never the ones with the greatest technical value; generally just the posts that were the most entertaining.  It's pretty inevitable with anonymous free voting.

Comment: lol, once he collects enough reputation points, Frosty will get an E-Mail from Careers.SE inviting him to start a profile. It might even work as long as he doesn't check the "relocate" option